# Python Programming

Tags: python

this is the problem I am working on. I have been programming for a total of 9 days so I am very new. I am attempting to write a function that generates a random integer between -1,200 and 1,200, and returns a statement dependent of the number. The statements are:  number generated: is greater than 800, return ‘Heidi wins’/ less than or equal to 800 and is an EVEN number, return ‘Magic wins’. / less than or equal to 800 and ends with a 3, return ‘Tally wins’. / less than or equal to 800 and ends with a 5, print ‘Chelsea wins’. Otherwise, print ‘Big Girl wins’. Here is my program so far: please help with finishing it up. thank you.

```
def sillyGame(n):
    mychoices=[
    number=random.choice(myChoices)
    inputNum=raw_input("Enter a number:")

    numbers=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.']
    isValidNumber=True 
    for ch in inputNum:
        for element in numbers:
            isMatch=False
            if ch ==element:
                isMatch=True 
                break 
            if isMatch==False:
                isValidNumber==False
                break 
            if isValidNumber==True:
                print("this is a valid number")
            else:
                print("this is not a valid number")
```

Comment: Your title is a bit too specific. Can you be more vague?

Comment: You need to phrase this as a question, rather than a debugging request.

Comment: So...what's the actual question?  We can't just "finish it up" for/with you; you have to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Better effort than stackoverflow.com/questions/14993398/python-programming

Comment: sorry. I am confused on how to generate the step for generating less than or equal to 800 and is an EVEN number, returning ‘Magic wins’. / less than or equal to 800 and ends with a 3, . One of these would be great.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is as you stated in your comments, then...

To detect if x is less than 800:
    `if x < 800`

To detect if x is even:
    `if x % 2 == 0`

To detect if x ends in a 3:
    `str(x)[-1] == "3"`

And any combination uses the keywords `or` or `and`:
    `if x < 800 and x % 2 == 0:`

Hope that helps.